# How to access super-class property in sub-class component template? Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an abstract super class that defines a property "proposal".

```
export abstract class myBaseClass {
  public proposal: Proposal;
}
```

and a class that extends it

```
export class mySubClassComponent Component extends myBaseClass{
    constructor() {
      super();
  }
}
```

I try to access the property "proposal" of myBaseClass in the template of mySubClassComponent like this:

`*ngIf="proposal.position"`

but I'm getting the following error

TypeError: Cannot read property 'position' of undefined

how can I have access to this property inside the mySubClassComponent tempalte?

Comment: You access it correctly but `proposal` is `undefined` when Angular evaluates the `ngIf` condition. If it is defined later, try `*ngIf="proposal?.position"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing it correctly. However, you have defined the type but, in fact, the class property is actually `undefined`.

Just add a null check in your ngIf and you will be done:

`*ngIf="proposal?.position"`

This will avoid undesired errors if `proposal` is declared but its value is **undefined**.

Basically, to make it clearer, this:

```
export abstract class myBaseClass {
  public proposal: Proposal;
}
```

is the same as this:

```
export abstract class myBaseClass {
  public proposal: Proposal = undefined;
}
```

Keep in mind that, in typescript, declaring a variable type have no effects after the code is compiled. If a variable is undefined, it will be undefined at runtime, regardless the type you have declared in your typescript code.